# Session Variables Expiring

Tags: php, session-variables, session-state, session-timeout, sessionid

I have a shopping cart app using a temporary MySQL table to store cart contents.  Each row of the cart table has the session value saved to uniquely identify that row.  I'm setting the initial value using the following:

```
$session_id = session_id();
```

Each time a user adds an item to their cart, I run a query to count the number of products in their cart and save that value using the following:

```
$_SESSION["total_cart_products"] = $cart_total_products['total_cart_products'];
```

On the web site, the cart page is generated each time it is loaded by querying the cart table by passing the $session_id file and pulling the results.  I'm displaying a the total cart products in the header so the user always knows how many items are their cart.

This all works great except that somehow the total cart products session is expiring before the $session_id.  Because the cart page will still work even thought the total cart products session has expired and displaying 0 in the header.

I would think both sessions would end at the same time, but they are not.  What am I missing with all this?

Thanks

Brett

Comment: Nearly all shopping website use cookies for this. http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php Despite cookies reputation, they are very practical.  However in Europe new laws have made the use of them restricted to the consent of the user.

Comment: Probably, the cart page is working even after the session is expired because you are querying with `$session_id` which is still present after the session has expired. Do you have access to your php.ini ? if so, [read this](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/11) and check what is your session expires time.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.  Alon, I'm requesting the $session_id each time the cart page is loaded/updated.  How is that session still alive but the the other not?  Maybe cookies are the way to go, but I would still like to understand what is going on with sessions and what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I never found an answer for my question - why it appears my session variable is timing out but the main session is not.

I switch things to use cookies and delete the cookie on successful checkout.